# Selenium4 is returning 'ELEMENTS' Dictionary rather than actual elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium4

Selenium4 is returning 'ELEMENTS' Dictionary rather than actual elements

For example when I try

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//input')
```

I get the dictionary of invalid elements like following

```
[{'ELEMENT':'0.02131234234312'},{'ELEMENT':'0.02131234234312'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `'w3c': False` then you will face this issue, Changing it to `'w3c': True` solves this

Confirmed for Chrome atleast